# How can I read email with HTML format in a Delphi application?

Tags: delphi, imap, delphi-2007, html-email, indy10

I have created a program that can read email from Exchange 2007. However, it can only read the body of the email in plain-text format. When I tried to retrieve email in HTML format, my software cannot read the body and it always blank. I am using Delphi 2007 and IMAP 9.

#### Update:

Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.tmrCekTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  TheFlags: TIdMessageFlagsSet;
  TheUID: string;
  TheMsg: TIdMessage;
  MailBoxName: string;
  MyClass: TComponent;
begin
  MailBoxName := 'INBOX';
  if TheImap.SelectMailBox(MailBoxName) = False then
  begin
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
    ShowMessage('Error selecting '+MailBoxName);
    Exit;
  end;
  TheMsg := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
  nCount := TheImap.MailBox.TotalMsgs;
  TheMsg.ContentType := 'multipart/alternative';
  TheMsg.Encoding := meMime;
  if nCount = 0 then begin
    StringGrid1.RowCount := 2;
    StringGrid1.Cells[0, 1] := '';
    StringGrid1.Cells[1, 1] := '';
    StringGrid1.Cells[2, 1] := '';
    StringGrid1.Cells[3, 1] := '';
    ShowMessage('There are no messages in '+MailBoxName);
  end else begin
    StringGrid1.RowCount := nCount + 1;
    for i := 0 to nCount-1 do begin
      TheImap.GetUID(i+1, TheUID);
      TheImap.UIDRetrieveFlags(TheUID, TheFlags);
      TheImap.UIDRetrieve(TheUID, TheMsg);
      //TheImap.UIDRetrieveHeader(TheUID, TheMsg);
      StringGrid1.Cells[0, i+1] := IntToStr(i+1);
      StringGrid1.Cells[1, i+1] := TheMsg.From.Address;
      //StringGrid1.Cells[1, i+1] := TheUID;
      if mfSeen in TheFlags then
        StringGrid1.Cells[2, i+1] := 'Yes'
      else begin
        StringGrid1.Cells[2, i+1] := 'No';
      end;
    end;
 end;
```

Comment: And how do you read it now? Can you post code? Maybe your approach is all wrong, but it could be there's only a tiny little error.

Comment: What function did you call? What did you pass to this function? What error arose?

Comment: IMAP 9? There's the problem. Current technology has only reached support for IMAP 4. You'll have to get back in your time machine and wait till the world catches up.

Answer (score 3):

The contents of MIME-encoded emails, such as HTML emails (if plain-text and/or attachments are also present) are stored in the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` property, not in the `TIdMessage.Body` property.  You need to look at the email's actual `ContentType` property to know which property `TIdMessage` parsed the email into.

Answer (score 0):

Using MAPI, I usually try to get the `PR_BODY_HTML` property as string; if that’s empty, I retrieve the `PR_HTML` property.

```
  const
    PR_HTML = $10130102;
    PR_BODY_HTML = $1013001E;
```

This usually works for me.  Of course, maybe you’re using different technology altogether, but you’re not giving us much to work with...

Comment: @Robin: Ah, Indy!  Could you edit your question to include this info, e.g. "...that can read email from Exchange.  I’m using the TIdIMAP control from Indy 10.1.5.".  And... _where_ is your code? (Don’t forget to use the [{}] button when you want to display code here on SO).