# how can I get email in plain text? I'm using imap indy10 and delphi7

Tags: delphi, imap, delphi-7, indy10

I'm using the following code, but I'm getting html or even base64, I don't know how to decode that in plain text. What is the correct way to read the email content in my delphi app?

```
var
  TheFlags: TIdMessageFlagsSet;
  TheUID: string;
  nCount: integer;
  TheMsg: TIdMessage;
  MailBoxName: string;
  lacadena:string;
begin
  nCount := TheImap.MailBox.TotalMsgs;
  for i := 0 to nCount do 
  begin
    TheImap.GetUID(i, TheUID)
    TheImap.UIDRetrieveText(TheUID, lacadena);

    dbmmoemcontent.text  :=lacadena;
  end;
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read email with HTML format in a Delphi application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076658/how-can-i-read-email-with-html-format-in-a-delphi-application)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `UIDRetreive()` instead of `UIDRetrieveText()`.  `UIDRetreive()` retrieves the entire email, headers and all, and then decodes it into a `TIdMessage`.  `UIDRetrieveText()`, on the other hand, retrieves just the raw text of the email body without any headers, and is not decoded in any way other than to convert the raw bytes into a `String`.

Comment: Remy, did you mean to say "UIDRetrieveText(), on the other hand..."?

Comment: So what if bandwidth is matter and we don't need attachments?

Comment: @AminAlinezhad then you would need to first retrieve the email's structure using `UIDRetrieveStructure()`, then analyze it to determine the part(s) you want, and then retrieve the content of each part using `UIDRetrievePart...()`